# Multicolumn - Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: tables, errors, multicolumn

I'm trying to build the following table, but I get the error in the title. I'm sure it has something to do with the \multicolumn function, but I can't see what's wrong with it. Help?

```
\begin{table} [h]
\centering
\caption{Belastninger for K6, M og L i BSim.}
\label{tab:belastninger}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]
{\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} Lokale & System & Beskrivelse & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Tidsplan} & \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} & & & Regulering & Tidsangivelse \\
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have an extra `&`: with `\multicolumn{2}{c}{...}` the `&` is implicitly given, so that line should have only three of them. Why enclosing the `tabular` in `\makebox`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is due to a typo